# Phoenix Live Reload working intermittently

Tags: emacs, elixir, phoenix-framework, livereload, spacemacs

I'm trying to figure out why Phoenix live reload works "most of the time" but not always.

My `config.exs` has:

```
# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :bespoke_work, BespokeWork.Web.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$},
      ~r{priv/gettext/.*(po)$},
      ~r{lib/bespoke_work/web/views/.*(ex)$},
      ~r{lib/bespoke_work/web/templates/.*(eex)$}
    ]
  ]
```

Whenever I edit one of the templates that ends in `*.html.eex` it usually works right away. But sometimes it does not. And when live reload doesn't work, no matter how many times I try to refresh the page / clear the cache or go salsa dancing, it just won't refresh the content.

My folder structure is like this:

`/name/lib/name/web/templates/page
                                 |-index.html.eex
                                 |-menu.html.eex
                                 |-module[1-5].html.eex`

*(there are five modules files, the first being module1.html.eex and so on)*

Is the fact that the files are not directly under the `templates` folder a problem? (They're inside the `templates/page` folder)

The `index.html` is rendered inside the `layout/app.html.eex` layout and, inside the `index` file, there are calls to render the `menu` and the other modules.

Not sure what I am missing here.

I tried running `mix phx.digest` manually, it didn't made any difference (it is already being triggered whenever needed).

How can I fix this behavior?

**Phoenix 1.3.0-rc.2**

**Phoenix Live Reload 1.0.8**

**Elixir 1.4.5**

**Erlang/OTP 20**

**Impaciência 10**

Comment: Are you storing front end dependencies inside folders that are "reloadable"? This usually causes a lot of trouble with Phoenix reload because it takes a lot of time to reload all the `node_modules`

Comment: Not sure about that @Haito. Although it doesn't really matter how long I wait or how many times I press "reload"/"refresh", sometimes it just won't reload.

Comment: Like right now... that's why I came back here to check if there was any answer :D

Comment: Maybe you think it is not reloading because it takes so long to reload.

Comment: Don't think so, I let it rest for an hour while doing other things...

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit: Spacemacs [lock files](http://spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html#orgheadline18).

As part of my workflow is working with Front-end specs, sometimes I need to adjust things by the pixel or make some other minor (**and really fast**) adjustment: as when you noticed you have a typo or something.

In those situations, what appears to happen is the following:

1. I switch to Spacemacs.
2. As soon as I start typing (switch to Evil Mode insert state), Spacemacs creates an lock file in the same directory.
3. Phoenix Live Reload notices the change in the directory and well, live reloads the code (which is still the same because the auto-save file is not used by the app).
4. When I save the altered file, usually right away, Live Reload was still refreshing the browser from the detected auto-save file creation.

Although I still can't understand why simply refreshing the screen (with Browser Cache disabled on Chrome) won't display the proper code.